# How to generate a closed orbit of celestial objects

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

I'm creating an orbit simulator and my planet is moving in odd elliptical orbits that aren't closed. First of all, is this even correct? Second of all, even if it is, how must I change the parameters to generate a closed orbit and what are the prerequisites for one.
Here is my simple code in Java:

```
        float deltaX = planet.getPos().x - this.pos.x;
        float deltaY = planet.getPos().y - this.pos.y;
        float alpha = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX));

        float distance = (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(deltaX, 2) + Math.pow(deltaY, 2));
        float F = G * this.m * planet.getM() / distance * distance;
        this.force.x = F * MathUtils.cosDeg(alpha);
        this.force.y = F * MathUtils.sinDeg(alpha);

        this.vel.x += (this.force.x / this.m) * deltaTime;
        this.vel.y += (this.force.y / this.m) * deltaTime;

        this.pos.x += this.vel.x * deltaTime;
        this.pos.y += this.vel.y * deltaTime;
```

The math is basically me getting the main force of the two planets with $F =  G* {m*M \over r^2}$ and using simple trigonometry I solve for the $x, y$ coordinates because I am in a 2D coordinate system.

Here are the parameters I feed the planets:

```
        planet1 = new Planet(20, 1, 800, 450); # r=20, m=1, pos=800, 450
        planet1.setVel(new Vector2(0, 200));
        planet2 = new Planet(40, 332000, 400, 450); # r=40, m = 332000, pos = 400, 450
```

(ignore the fact the lines are not in the same position as the planet but they are the correct orbit)
I've researched a little and apparently its called a rosetta orbit? But yeah, I don't know how to get an elliptical closed orbit. I have managed to get a circular orbit however.
[image]

Comment: If you can read Python, you may find this answer of mine useful: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/48477/16685

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is order of operations.

`float F = G * this.m * planet.getM() / distance * distance;`

Should be

`float F = G * this.m * planet.getM() / (distance * distance);`

The former gives you Constant Gravity, instead of Inverse-square gravity, resulting in the rosette orbit.

Comment: well that wasn't very smart of me, thank you it worked

Comment: The orbit isn't fully closed though? It keeps getting smaller

Comment: @eisa.exe I imagine that's probably to do with the size of your chosen `deltaTime` and floating point issues. [PM 2Ring's comment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/719068/how-to-generate-a-closed-orbit-of-celestial-objects/719072?noredirect=1#comment1608266_719068) on the initial question links to an answer that discusses those.